# What happens when you hit apache conf memory limit?

Tags: apache-2.4, memory-usage

1. I'm wondering, if I have a script on one of my websites running and at some point it reaches 100% of the servers ram, will the script stop running?
2. And what happens if I set the memory limit higher than the servers ram?

Edit: If that matters, I'm wondering this about Linux(CentOS and Ubuntu in my case)

Comment: That depends very much on the operating system you're using and not so much on apache  as far as I know. Please edit your question to include that.

Comment: I hope my edit clarified it a little bit

Comment: @HBruijn is on the right track, this is largely dependent on OS/Kernel and the configurations for virtual memory/swap http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/vm-intro.html https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/s-memory-tunables.html